# calling an object instantiated in one class, from other classes in java program

Tags: java, swing, object

I have three classes.

Class A extends jFrame (Which is the main user interface)

Class B extends jPanel (This one is called to appear inside of the main jFrame)

and Class C to do some file handling and processing.

What I am trying to do is have an object of Class C instantiated in Class A and calling it in Class B.

*Here's some sample code:*

```
Public Class A extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Public A(){
       C ObjectOfC = new C();
       B panelWithButtons = new B();
    }
}

public Class B extends javax.swing.JPanel{
    String s = ObjectOfC.getName();
}

public Class C{
    String name;
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to get this done? or is it a lost cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.  You probably want to build either a constructor or a method for B that takes object C as an argument.

Example:

```
Public Class A extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Public A(){
       C objectOfC = new C();
       B panelWithButtons = new B(objectOfC);
    }
}

public Class B extends javax.swing.JPanel{

    String s;

    public B (C objectOfC) {
        this.s = objectOfC.getName();
    }
}

public Class C{
    String name;
    public String getName(){
    return this.name;
    }
}
```

A singleton example as per your comment:

```
Public Class A extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Public A(){
       B panelWithButtons = new B();
    }
}

public Class B extends javax.swing.JPanel{
    String s;
    objectOfC C = C.getInstance();

    this.s = objectOfC.getName();
}

public class C {
    private static String name;
    private static final C INSTANCE = new C();

    private C() {}

    public static C getInstance() {
       return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

A singleton example with changing variables (and errors removed from the original code.):

```
public class A extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public A() {
        C objectOfC = C.getInstance();
        objectOfC.setName("Bob");
        B panelWithButtons = new B(objectOfC);
        System.out.println("objectOfC_A:" + objectOfC.getName()); //return "George"
    }
}

public class B extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public B (C objectOfC) {
        C c2 = C.getInstance();

        objectOfC.setName("Fred");
        c2.setName("George");
        System.out.println("objectOfC_B:" + objectOfC.getName()); //returns "George"
        System.out.println("c2: " + c2.getName()); //returns "George"
    }

}

public class C {
    private static String name;
    private static final C INSTANCE = new C();

    private C() {}

    public static C getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return C.name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        C.name = name;
    }
}
```

With this example you can call C.getInstance from any class and they will all be sharing the same instance.  However, you must be careful with how you are going to access the object; there are plenty of tutorials out there about multithreading singletons which you will need to do if you plan on modifying data in the C instance from multiple objects at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. I actually have many classes like B (JPanels), I only want exactly one Object of C callable from all other classes .. I do have constructors but I didnt try passing the object .. I'm gonna try it and update my post.. you mentioned other ways can be used .. can you please elaborate? my whole program hangs on this

Comment: If you want a single instance of objectOfC available to all classes then you probably want a singleton.  I'll edit my answer to include an example.

Comment: One last question .. Say I want to modify attributes of the C instance(from the other classes), I would also use singleton? From what I know once an instance is declared Final the attributes cannot be changed..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your question. Just the instance is final, you can still change any static variables. I added a third example to my answer with a setter to illustrate, and also with all the syntax errors from the original example removed. You can try it out if you like.